# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with django-storages

Tags: django, segmentation-fault, django-storage, python-django-storages

I'm using **Django 2.x** and **Django-storages** to upload files to the **S3 Bucket**.

While running the sample test from `manage.py shell`, it gives the following error and terminates the console.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The console log as per the doc.

```
In [1]: from django.core.files.storage import default_storage                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: default_storage.exists('storage_test')                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[2]: False

In [3]: file = default_storage.open('storage_test', 'w')                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [4]: file.write('storage content')                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[4]: 15

In [5]: file.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [6]: default_storage.exists('storage_test')                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[6]: True

In [7]: file = default_storage.open('storage_test', 'r')                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [8]: file.read()                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

File is uploaded to the S3 Bucket but unable to access or read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those searching for an answer. This was an issue with the Python version. Upgrading python version worked for me.

Here is the detailed answer: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/794#issuecomment-603116398